# On update to Java 17, Intellij started with this error : Unable to find method StringGroovyMethods.capitalize(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

My Intellij IDE was good and never had any issue with different gradle version, but the moment have updated the Java version from 1.8 to 17, started seeing this error

I had spent lot of time on this issue, by going through all the suggestions here and in other threads.

> Unable to find method ''java.lang.String org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.capitalize(java.lang.String)''.
> Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Comment: While this is *interesting*, it isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with different with different versions of gradle and switched back to java 1.8, but didn't help.

Finally, updated the Intellij to latest version 2022.1.4 from 2019, then this disappeared.

Comment: What question does this answer?